# Get Requests returning 404 on IIS but works locally

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-6

I am hosting my MVC app (Angular Js + MVC 4) on an IIS  6.0 server.

My Route Configuration below:

```
 public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

below is the controller code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
         public JsonResult GetAppSettings()
    {
        try
        {
            string useAdvancedSearch = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["UseAdvancedSearch"];

            return Json(new { userAdvancedSearch = Boolean.Parse(useAdvancedSearch) }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { message = ex.ToString() }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}
```

My Ajax call in the angular js controller is below:

```
var ConfigService =
    function (configConstants, $http, $q) {
        this.getAppSettings = function () {
            var d = $q.defer();
            var get = $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: "Home/GetAppSettings",
                dataType: 'json',
                headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
            });
            get.then(function (response) {
                d.resolve(response.data);
                console.log(response.data);
            }, function (err) {
                console.error(JSON.stringify(err));
                d.reject(err);
            });
            return d.promise;
        };
    };
```

This call is giving correct data in the local IIS express but when i run the same thing on the IIS, I am getting 404 error.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

My Url in localhost is : `http://localhost:63555/Home/GetAppSettings`

The IIS server URL is : `http://******/apsecureeditor/WebApp/Home/GetAppSettings`
The project is placed inside **apsecureeditor/webapp** folder on the server. 
I am getting 404 error when i do this on the IIS server. 
My framework is MVC 4, .net 4.0 and the version of IIS is 6.0.

Is there anything I am missing here to include?

EDIT 1: 
I tried the below changes also on the server but no luck.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/deployment/using-asp-net-mvc-with-different-versions-of-iis-cs

Here is my routeconfig after this change.

```
  public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
             "Root",
             "",
             new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
             );

            routes.MapRoute(
                "Default",
                "{controller}.aspx/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = "" }
              );
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing your MVC app in the apsecureeditor/webapp folder does not alter the route to pages in your app because you are calling actions from your controllers using the routing set for your project not the location of files/views on the local (server) hard drive.  Try loading the URL exactly as you would the local project, i.e. remove the apsecureeditor/webapp from the URL entirely.

Comment: My app's home page works fine with this url : http://jwebtst201/apsecureeditor/WebApp/ but the other actions doesnt seem to load.

Comment: That would suggest there's something else wrong with the way you've setup the site on iis, what happens when you go to the route url?

Comment: When i go to the route url, i get 404 error. "The page cannot be found. 
The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: Then your problem is not related to your code, the website is likely not setup correctly in some way on iis or perhaps there's something in your webconfig/publishing that's awry.  I'd suggest starting a new question directed at iis and that kind of thing asking why your website is 404ing and providing information on what you've done to setup the site so far.